# MIDI score following

Tags: android, ios, midi, coremidi

Are there any opensource options for iOS/Android score following of MIDI files?

I think on iOS the CoreMIDI framework may support this but can't understand it at all? How do you use it and what is it for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is too open. I'm going to have to say 'no there are no opensource score following options for these devices'. There are some solutions that you can look at to get started, http://code.google.com/p/mobilesynth/ is a favorite of mine.

CoreMIDI will definitely not do this. CoreMIDI provides access to the iOS MIDI server - period.